# Invert Z depth hides some objects completely

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I used a material with Invert Z depth to make an outline but it suddenly decided to hide part of the model completely...
[image]
It uses the same materials as the rest of the model
If i join the hidden part with another object of the model, it works fine, and if I make a new outline object for the hidden part, it works as an outline but the whole thing is behind everything else...
Any Idea why this happened?

Comment: For non-photorealistic rendering, such as outlines I'd recommend using Freestyle.